# SessionBased vs Token Authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, session, django-rest-framework, token

The DRF documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication) states that

> Token authentication is appropriate for client-server setups, such as
> native desktop and mobile clients.

and

> Session authentication is appropriate for AJAX clients that are running in the same session context as your website.

Yet most of the tutorials and StackOverflow questions/answers about Django Rest Framework Authentication suggest using Token authentication in most of the cases, even with webapps.

I'm implementing a webapp using Django/Django Rest Framework as the backend and Angular as the front-end.
Which authentication scheme should I use?
What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169145/django-rest-framework-session-auth-vs-token-auth-csrf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Session Based Authentication

In the session based authentication, the server will create a session for the user after the user logs in. The session id is then stored on a cookie on the user’s browser. While the user stays logged in, the cookie would be sent along with every subsequent request. The server can then compare the session id stored on the cookie against the session information stored in the memory to verify user’s identity and sends response with the corresponding state!

[image]

## Token Based Authentication

Many web applications use token instead of sessions for authentication. In the token based application, the server creates token with a secret and sends the token to the client. The client stores the token (usually in local storage) and includes token in the header with every request. The server would then validate the token with every request from the client and sends the response.

[image]

The biggest difference here is that the user’s state is not stored on the server, as the state is stored inside the token on the client side instead. Most of the modern web applications use token for authentication for reasons including scalability and mobile device authentication.

Comment: Worth noting that the default implementation of token authentication in Django Rest Framework is **not** JWT. It is backed by a database so the user's state is stored on the server. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: As @Neil Mentioned, Token Authentication in Rest Framework is not JWT

Comment: yes, I just used JWT as an example. please choose the type of token appropriately.

Comment: Did you mean JWT by Token Authentication? 
Because default token authentication in django is not JWT, and it can't store user state, if it has to be maintained, it has to be done on server unless it's JWT.