# Is session auth possible in Django Rest Framework with a mobile client?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, quasar

I want my application to have a mobile client (non native, built using Quasar). As I understand token auth will work, so I have chosen and implemented JWT for the web app though I havent tested the mobile client yet. I was wondering is it possible/recommended to use session auth in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I believe session authentication could work with a mobile interface, however it is usually preferred to use token authentication for this situation.

The difference between the two is that in token based authentication, the user's state is not stored on the server - instead your mobile app will handle this through the use of the auth token. Token authentication is also preferred over session authentication for scalability reasons.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66085236/11103705) gives a nice overview of the 2 approaches

[The official DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) gives you some insight on how to integrate these methods.

Personally, I would only use session authentication for a small website that I know is not possible to extend to other platforms (i.e. a mobile app or desktop app), as you dont have to worry about passing the token in the frontend so implementation becomes slightly easier/quicker in that regard.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use session based auth in this situation as well. Token based auth is not a must have. however it is good to start with session based auth and then use other type of authentication in the system. django & it's eco system provide plug able auth