# Django Caching Token based Authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, caching, redis

I am using DRF for Token authentication as: while a user login, i am creating a token and for every user request  Django is hitting database (for verifying token and get user info). So i want to cache the tokens of currently logged IN users into my Redis cache (running on same server). So that i can avoid a lot of Database hits and my request/response cycle will be faster.
I am new to django and got struct to implement this. Please help me with code or should i change from tokenbased to session based authentication?.
(My frontend is mobile app, So i should use token based auth only.)

I am currently using DRF token based authentication for every view as:-

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])        #checks for token and gets the user object
def Test_view(request):
    #some db queries
    Return Response({'test':'returned'})
```

created login view as follows:-

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def UserLogin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key,'name':user.fname+' '+user.lname,
                             'phone':user.phone,'username':user.username,'email':user.email})
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'})
```

in my settings.py:-

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

and i am currently using redis cache:-

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
      'LOCATION': "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
      'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
            'IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS': True,
        },
      'TIMEOUT': None,
   }
}
```

Comment: *”My frontend is mobile app, So i should use token based auth only.”* is it written in any rule book?

Comment: You can use stateless tokens like [**JWT**](https://jwt.io/introduction/) but you should know the security vulnerabilities this comes with too.

Comment: It's not a rule but it's not optimal, You can refer this ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75927264/16320185)).  please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: ok so what i read from JWT is that:- it will encrypt the token+userinfo and generate a token, for every request we will decrypt this and validate the token and get userinfo (hence no database hit).
Am i right?

Comment: could you please mention those security vulnerabilities with jwt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want stateless auth that will not affect your database in the long run, consider [`JWT`](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

**Install `simplejwt`**:

```py
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

**Use `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication`**:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTStatelessUserAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

**Generate token**:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refreshToken = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    return {
        'accessToken': str(refreshToken.access_token),
        'refreshToken': str(refreshToken)
    }

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def UserLogin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            tokens = get_tokens_for_user(user)
            return Response(
                        tokens | {
                            'name': f"{user.fname} {user.lname}",
                            'phone': user.phone,
                            'username': user.username,
                            'email': user.email
                        }
                    )
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'})
```

Reference: [**simplejwt**](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: thankyou for the code, can you please confirm this last doubt:-
can i use this in **production**?(all requests are **HTTPS**)